# Skiena, The Algorithm Design Manual, regarding heapsort (page 111)

Tags: algorithm, math, equation

I am Self Studying the "The Algorithm Design Manual" book. Im at the moment studying chapter 4 (HeapSort) and on Page 111 there is an equation that i cant wrap my head around

it goes like

> Space efficiency thus demands that we not allow holes in our
>   tree—i.e., that each level be packed as much as it can be. If so, only
>   the last level may be incomplete. By packing the elements of the last
>   level as far to the left as possible, we can represent an n-key tree
>   using exactly n elements of the array. If we did not enforce these
>   structural constraints, we might need an array of size 2n to store the
>   same elements. Since all but the last level is always filled, the
>   height h of an n element heap is logarithmic because:  
>   [image]so h =     lg n

What i don't understand is how one can determine h =logn from the above equation? my math is rusty but to my knowledge  it should be like h =log((n+1)/2)

I hope there are people here who have gone through this book and would be able to help me out understanding this

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you get `h = log((n+1) / 2)`? Assuming base 2 logs, we have:

```
2^(h+1) - 1 >= n
2^(h+1) >= n+1 | apply log
log(2^(h+1)) >= log(n+1)
h+1 >= log(n+1)
(log n)+1 >= log(n+1)

=> h = O(log n)
```

The book should have said `h = O(log n)` to be a little more accurate, but this is also fine.

Read about [big-oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to see why the constants don't matter. In fact, the base of the logarithm doesn't matter either.

Comment: thanks, yes if the book said h = O(log n) then i would not have been confused. and as to how i got h = log((n+1) / 2)  is by 2^{h+1} >= n+1 which equals to 2^h x 2^1 = n + 1 which equals to 2^h = (n+1)/2 and there by h = log ((n+1)/2) . is this incorrect ? if so could you please point out where i got it wrong ( i hope i did not do a careless mistake)

Comment: @user119020 ah, I see. No, it's correct and equivalent to what I did, it just looked odd to me at first. But yes, using big-oh would indeed have made things clearer.

Comment: pretty sure the base of the log does matter... The base of O(b^n) would matter since 3^n is in no way bounded above by 2^n. I dont see why it would be different with logs.

Comment: @GettnDer because `log_a(x) = log_b(x) / log_b(a)`. `log_b(a)` is a constant. Because logarithms in two different bases differ by a constant, log bases do not matter in big-oh notation.

Comment: @IVlad Ahhh you are correct. Their growth rate is then the same.

Answer (score 2):

What Skienna's book is stating (not clear enough, though) is that `h` is **asymptotically** logarithmic. Namely,

2^{h+1} >= n+1 is equivalent to

h+1 >= log(n+1),

so you ignore constants and get h=O(log n). Your calculation is correct, it gives the same result, but you should observe asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: well did not know that you could ignore constants like that specially in a log equation.my way of thinking was 2^{h+1} >= n+1  which equals to 
2^h x 2^1 = n + 1  which equals to 2^h = (n+1)/2 and there by
h = log ((n+1)/2) and i also don't get  where log(2^x)=x. comes in handy

Comment: @user119020 You can ignore constants when dealing with asymptotic complexity, which should have been stated more clear in the Skienna's book. Also log((n+1)/2)=log(n+1) - log2 = log(n+1) - 1, so by ignoring constants you get the same thing.